# jQuery to keep Active and inactive user using php and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having problem with some jquery code that I need help with.

I have a user login system and have created a row in the admin section where I can click and change the status of a user from active to inactive and vice versa.

The link works and initially on page load the classes are loaded with a red color applied to inactive users and green for active users but when I click the link/button the link reverts back to a plain link with no color classes applied to the button.

The jQuery is

```js
clickActive : function(thisIdentity) {
  "use strict";
  $(document).on('click', thisIdentity, function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var thisObj = $(this);
   var thisUrl = thisObj.data('url');
   var thisStatus = thisObj.hasClass('btn-success') ? '0' : '1';
   $.getJSON(thisUrl, function(data) {
    if (data && !data.error) {
     if (!adminObject.isEmpty(data.replace)) {
      thisObj.replaceWith(data.replace);
     }
    }
   });
  });
},
```

I cannot figure out how to ensure either the jQuery or PHP keeps the active class applied to the colour.

```html
<td class="ta_r">
    <a href="#" data-url= "<?php echo $data['objUrl']->getCurrent(array('action', 'id'), false, array('action', 'active', 'id', $item['id'])); ?>" class="clickActive btn <?php echo $item['active'] == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger'; ?>">
    <?php echo $item['active'] == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Can anyone advise how I can click on the link and if it is active the colour green is applied and if inactive the colour red is applied.

Thank you

Comment: more informations please. i mean more code ;-) advise check $item with var_dump($item)

Comment: The rest of the code is -                                                                        <?php

$active = $client['active'] == 1 ? 0 : 1;


if ($objUser->update(array('active' => $active), $client['id'])) {
 
 $replace  = '<a href="#" data-url="';
 $replace .= $this->objUrl->getCurrent();
 $replace .= '" class="clickActive">';
 $replace .= $active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
 $replace .= '</a>';
 
 echo Helper::json(array('error' => false, 'replace' => $replace));
 
} else {
 throw new Exception('Record could not be updated');
}

Comment: But I think the problem is in the jQuery code.  This code - var thisStatus = thisObj.hasClass('btn-success') ? '0' : '1'; is not being used anywhere in the jQuery code.

Comment: The code I am amending to my own use is - <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.status_checks',function(){
var status = ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) ? '0' : '1';
var msg = (status=='0')? 'Deactivate' : 'Activate';
if(confirm("Are you sure to "+ msg)){
 var current_element = $(this);
 url = "ajax.php";
 $.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url: url,
 data: {id:$(current_element).attr('data'),status:status},
 success: function(data)
  {   
   location.reload();
  }
 });
 }      
});
</script>